# fetching correct row according to time span

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table for structure like this

```
  empid   fromdate       todate       office_ID
    1     2012-03-01      2014-04-2      1
    1     2014-04-03      ----           2
    2     2012-03-01      2014-04-2       2
    3     2012-03-01      2014-04-2        1
```

from this table i want to fetch that at some month 
for ex. for **may 205**  where was employee 1 
for that i have designed query

```
    select* from tbl_emp_office where   (year(From_date)*100+ month(From_date)) < '201505'
```

but it is not giving correct answer for all users

if employee currently working at some office then todate will be not known hence it is null (this logic can be changed if you suggest some better )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
select office_id 
  from employee_history 
    where year(fromdate) <= 2015 
      and month(fromdate) <= 5 
      and (
        (month(todate) >= 5 and year(todate) >= 2015) 
        or todate is null
      )
      and empid = 1;
```

The query uses mysql functions to break the dates into year and month, and then makes sure that the month and year you are looking for is equal to or after their startdate, and that their todate is either null, or occurs after the month/year combo you are looking for.

This should also include offices they were in for a partial month.